# How a feature descriptior for traffic sign detection works in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to understand how Centroid to Contour (CtC) detector works. [Here](https://github.com/codehack9991/Speed-Limit-Sign-Recognition/blob/master/CtC/CtC.cpp) is a sample code that I have found on Github, and I am trying to understand what is the idea behind this. In this sample, the author trying to detect speed sign using CtC. There are just two important functions:

- pre_process()
- CtC_features

I have understood a part of the code and how it works but I have some problems in understanding how **CtC_features** function works.
If you can help me I would like to understand the following parts (just 3 points):

- Why if centroid.x > curr.x we need to add PI value to the angle result ( if (**centroid.x > curr.x) ang += 3.14159;  //PI**  )
- When we start selecting the features on line 97 we set the start angle ( **double ang = - 1.57079;**  ). Why is this half the pi value and negative? How was this value chosen?
- And a more general question, how can you know that what feature you select are related to speed limit sign? You find the centroid of the image and adjust the angle in the first step, but in the second step how can you know if ( while (feature_v[i].first > ang) ) the current angle is bigger than your hardcode angle ( **in first case ang = - 1.57079**) then we add that distance as a feature.

I would like to understand the idea behind this code and if someone with more experience and with some knowledge about trigonometry would help me it will be just great.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you provided is not the best, but let's see what happens.

I took this starting image of a sign:

[image: Original Image]

Then, `pre_process` is called, which basically runs a Canny edge detector, along with some tricks which should lead to a better edge detection. I won't look into them, but this is what it returns:

[image: pre_process result]

Not the greatest. Maybe some parameter tuning would help.

But now, `CtC_features` is called, which is the scope of the question. The role of `CtC_features` is to obtain some features for a machine learning algorithms. This amounts to finding a numerical description of the image which would help the ML algorithm detect the sign. Such a description can be anything. Think about how someone who never saw a STOP sign and does not know how to read would describe it. They would say something like "A red, flat plate, with 8 sides and some white stuff in the middle". Based on this description, someone might be able to tell it's a STOP sign. We want to do the same, but since computers are computers, we look for numerical features. And, with them, some algorithm could be trained to "learn" what features each sign has.

So, let's see what features does `CtC_features` obtains from the contours.

The first thing it does is to call [`findContours`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga17ed9f5d79ae97bd4c7cf18403e1689a). This function takes a binary image and returns arrays of points representing the contours of the image. Basically, it takes the edges and puts them into arrays of points. With connectivity, so we basically know which points are connected. If we use the code from here for visualization, we can see what happens:

[image: Contours]

So, the array `contours` is a `std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>>` and you have in each sub-array a continuous contour, here drawn with a different color.

Next, we compute the number of points (edge pixels), and do an average over their coordinates to find the centroid of the edge image. The centroid is the filled circle:

[image: centroid visualization]

Then, we iterate over all points, and create a vector of `std::pair<double, double>`, recording for each point the distance from the centroid and the angle. The angle function is defined at the bottom of the file as

```
double angle(Point2f a, Point2f b) {
    return atan((a.y - b.y) / (a.x - b.x));
}
```

It basically computes the angle of the line from `a` to `b` with respect to the x axis, using the arctangent function. I'll let you watch a [video](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/precalculus/trig-equations-and-identities-precalc/inverse-trig-functions-precalc/v/inverse-trig-functions-arctan) on arctangent, but tl;dr is that it gives you the angle from a ratio. In radians (a circle is 2 PI radians, half a circle is PI radians). The problem is that the function is periodic, with a period of PI. This means that there are 2 angles on the circle (the circle of all points at the same distance around the centroid) which give you the same value. So, we compute the ratio (the ratio is btw known as the tangent of the angle), apply the inverse function (arctangent) and we get an angle (corresponding to a point). But what if it's the other point? Well, we know that the other point is exactly with PI degrees offset (it is diametrically opposite), so we add PI if we detect that it's the other point.

The picture below also helps understand why there are 2 points:

[image]

The tangent of the angle is highlighted vertical distance,. But the angle on the other side of the diagonal line, which intersects the circle in the bottom left, also has the same tangent. The `atan` function gives the tangents only for angles on the left side of the center. Note that there are no 2 directions with the same tangent.

What the check does is to ask whether the point is on the right of the centroid. This is done in order to be able to add a half a circle (PI radians or 180 degrees) to correct for the result of `atan`.

Now, we know the distance (a simple formula) and we have found (and corrected) for the angle. We insert this pair into the vector `feature_v`, and we sort it. The sort function, called like that, sorts after the first element of the pair, so we sort after the angle, then after distance.

The `interval` variable:

```
int degree = 10;
double interval = double((double(degree) / double(360)) * 2 * 3.14159); //5 degrees interval
```

simply is value of `degree`, converted from degrees into radians. We need radians since the angles have been computed so far in radians, and degrees are more user friendly. Yep, the comment is wrong, the interval is 10 degrees, not 5.

The `ang` variable defined below it is -PI / 2 (a quarter of a circle):

```
double ang = - 1.57079;
```

Now, what it does is to divide the points around the centroid into bins, based on the angle. Each bin is 10 degrees wide. This is done by iterating over the points sorted after angle, all are accumulated until we get to the next bin. We are only interested in the largest distance of a point in each bin. The starting point should be small enough that all the direction (points) are captured.

In order to understand why it starts from -PI/2, we have to get back at the trigonometric function diagram above. What happens if the angle goes like this:

[image: negative tangent]

See how the highlighted vertical segment goes "downwards" on the y axis. This means that its length (and implicitly the tangent) is negative here. Also, the angle is considered to be negative (otherwise there would be 2 angles on the same side of the center with the same tangent). Now, we are interested in the range of angles we have. It's all the angles on the right side of the centroid, starting from the bottom at -PI/2 to the top at PI/2. A range of PI radians, or 180 degrees. This is also written in the documentation of [atan](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/atan):

> If no errors occur, the arc tangent of arg (arctan(arg)) in the range [-PI/2, +PI/2] radians, is returned.

So, we simply split all the possible directions (360 degrees) into buckets of 10 degrees, and take the distance of the farthest point in each bin. Since the circle has 360 degrees, we'll get 360 / 10 = 36 bins. Then, these are normalized such that the greatest value is 1. This helps a bit with the machine learning algorithm.

How can we know if the point we selected belongs to the sign? We don't. Most computer vision make some assumptions regarding the image in order to simplify the problem. The idea of the algorithm is to determine the shape of the sign by recording the distance from the center to the edges. This makes the assumption that the centroid is roughly in the middle of the sign. Depending on the ML algorithm used, and on the training data, different levels of robustness can be obtained.

Also, it assumes that (some of) the edges can be reliably identified. See how in my image, the algorithm was not able to detect the upper left edge?

The good news is that this doesn't have to be perfect. ML algorithms know how to handle this variation (up to some extent) provided that they are appropriately trained. It doesn't have to be perfect, but it has to be good enough. In order to answer what good enough means, what are the actual limitations of the algorithm, some more testing needs to be done, as well as some understanding of the ML algorithm used. But this is also why ML is so popular in vision: it can handle a lot of variation quite well.

At the end, we basically get an array of 36 numbers, one for each of the 36 bins of 10 degrees, representing the maximum distance of a point in the bin. I assume this is because the developer of the algorithm wanted a way to capture the shape of the sign, by looking at distances from center in various directions. This assumes that no edges are detected in the background, and the sign looks something like:

[image]

The max distance is used to pick the border, and not the or other symbols on the sign.

---

It is not directly used here, but a possibly related reading is the [Hough transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform), which uses a similar particularization to detect straight lines in an image.

Comment: The post got a lot longer than I intended, partially because it includes a bit of my thought process while I tried to understand the code. I hope it helps, and I hope it is detailed enough to help others too.

Comment: Hello @Paul92. Thank you for this detailed answer. I ditnd't understand all but I will re-read. So this guy used arctang (and not arcsin) because the distance between points was calculated with respect for x? And why is he intrested just for the bigger value froma bin? Thank you

Comment: you also said, "The atan function gives the tangents only for angles on the left side of the center" is not the right side? From what I know atan can calculate angles for quadrant 1 and 4 and they are on the right side of the center.

Comment: And another small thing "It's all the angles on the right side of the centroid, starting from the bottom at -PI/2 to the top at PI/2. A range of PI radians, or 180 degrees. This is also written in the documentation of atan:". But if I make some debut angle it starts at -1.57 and ends at 4.71. This means it travers the entire circle (1.57+4.71 = 2pi) and not just from -pi/2 to pi/2.

Comment: Any inverse trigonometric function could be used. `atan` tends to be preferred since it's easier: it's just y over x, while for `asin` you need to compute y over the distance. Here is available, so it wouldn't make any difference (except for the angle correction, which is different).

Comment: You use `atan` to get the angle between -pi/2 and pi/2, then apply the correction of pi/2 if needed. This means that you will get, for each point, the angle between the x axis and the point itself, which can run from -pi/2 up to 3pi/2. This is a full circle, so you have to iterate over the entire circle to analyse all the angles. I was referring in the cited section about the return value of `atan`- there you have a range from -pi/2 to pi/2. After the corection, this gets to a full circle (from -pi/2 to 3pi/2).

Comment: `atan` does give the result in the first and fourth quadrant (left of center), and pi/2 might need to be added to correct for points to the right of the center. My bad.

Comment: Great, now I understand.
Still is a problem with quadrans. You said that quadrants 1 and 4 are on the left side of the center. Is not on the right?
I mean the circle quadrans looks like this:
II  | I
________
III | IV

Comment: @Mike I keep confusing left and right and confusing you in the process. Sorry about that. See https://d2jmvrsizmvf4x.cloudfront.net/tLUQM6iFTgTmvxPDDwlw_trig+functions.jpg for the quadrants.